# How to do 2 WHERE statements in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I do 2 'WHERE' clauses in SQL in a single query?

I want something like this:

```
SELECT something1, something2, something3 WHERE 
something4 = 'blablabla' 
AND something3 LIKE '%blablablaaa%'
```

Comment: Did you check to see if what you wrote works?

Comment: Where's your `FROM (tablename)` ???? Other than that - this query should work with just about any relational DBMS ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your syntax is correct:

```
select * 
from table
where (col1 = 'a' or col2 = 'b') and col3 = 'c'
```

just to clarify - you cannot have two "where" clauses,
there will be one "where" with multiple conditions.